# Subclass With Changed Type in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, matrix, casting, type-conversion

Is it possible in Java to create a subclass and do a sort of find and replace for a type? To change an instance variable to be a `Integer` instead of a `Double`?

I am looking for a vector class that holds integers. I mean a real math vector, not a `java.util.Vector`.

In `org.apache.commons.math3` there are [`Vector2D`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/Vector2D.html) and [`ArrayRealVector`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html) classes, but they both only take `Double` for their coordinates.

I would love to be able to somehow subclass them to use `Integer`s instead. I know I could subclass the abstract class they extend from, but that seems like a whole ton of code deduplication, judging by how long their implementations are ([source of Vector2d](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/Vector2D.java?view=markup) and [source of ArrayRealVector](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/math/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/ArrayRealVector.java?view=markup)).

I know I could also typecast my `Integer`s to `Double`s when constructing and getting values back, but again this seems a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this once the base class is already created.

What you can do is create a base class which uses `generics`. This allows you to declare a type T that everything within them uses, you then use T within your class and when you use the type you decide what type to use for T within them.

Take a look at the `java.util.collections` package for a lot of examples.